# Windows 7 UAC approved / unapproved list

Tags: windows-7, ssrs, uac

**Problem:** Not able to print reports in CRM because of UAC block.

**Notes:** A user with local admin clicked no to the UAC prompt to install the Report Viewer in CRM while printing a report.
The prompt was for a program named "SQL Server Reporting Services 2008". Now this is blocked permanently.

**Question:** Is there a way to restore the UAC prompt for this program? If not for one program then for all UAC prompts.

However, I may not know what I am talking about. It might be that the CRM is not prompting to install the Report Viewer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, UAC doesn't ever *remember* answers in this way. I suspect your theory is correct, in that the first use of a feature prompted its installation and, hence, a UAC prompt. Perhaps the CRM took the failure as an indication not to prompt again.

As a test, temporarily disable UAC to see if it makes a difference. Otherwise, you might have to find a way to manually install the reporting tool. (I'd guess it's an MSI in the install media somewhere, but I've not used these tools)

Comment: You are right, UAC doesn't have the option of remembering the answer, either "yes" or "no". Remembering "yes" could lead to security issues and remembering "no" would cause to *a lot* of cases of blocking applications by mistake.